# Is it possible to use Facebook graph API to search through a user's status updates?

Tags: facebook

I understand it is possible to search through all public posts - but don't see a way to easily filter them by author.

I understand it is possible to search through a user's news feed - but it is not clear to me whether these would actually include the user's own status updates... and if they do, if there is a way to filter by author.

Is there a way to use the graph API to search within a user's status updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try https://graph.facebook.com/[user id]/statuses?access_token=[access token]

Requires the read_stream permission

Comment: Alex, thanks, but I am looking to be able to search the user's updates, not just view them.

Comment: add a `&q=<searchterm>` to the link